# Root User Can't run Files Off Desktop or Documents? Mojave 10.14.3

Tags: finder, mojave, privacy, administrator, root

Anybody else have this issue with root in Mojave (10.14.3)? I have root enabled and I try to run a simple .txt/.png/.pkg off the root desktop. It doesn’t run, I get an error in Console “Unable to load Info.plist eGPU Overrides.” and Finder crashes.

I have the same file in the Downloads Folder and try to open it and it runs just fine. I thought this had to do with TCC so I added Finder and TextEdit into the Full Disk Access inside System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access. Nothing, still same bug.

All my permissions seem to be set correctly for the root's directories and the files. This happened right after I upgraded to Mojave. I also tested this with a clean Mojave install. Same issue.

TLDR - Mojave 10.14.3 - Root Desktop - can’t open a file, Root Downloads Folder, yes I can open same said file?

Here is a gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrRvn.jpg